# Instance variable in python

Tags: python

I am new in python i read about Instance variable:

> A variable that is defined inside a method and belongs only to the
>   current instance of a class.

So i test it:

Consider this code:

```
class test:
    count=0
    def __init__(self):
          test.count += 1
```

I have a class that add count after Instantiation.
I run this:

```
t1=test() 
t1.count=100
```

and then I create  new instance:

```
t2=test()
t2.count  # 2
```

then create another instance:

```
t3=test()
t3.count  # 3
t2.count  # 3
```

and then :

```
t1.count  # I get 100
```

My question is why  `t2` and `t3` was update but if change value of instance variable of specific instance the  instance 's instance variable was not update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `t2` and `t3`, since you haven't defined an instance variable `count`, referring to, e.g., `t2.count` looks up the name in the class scope and evaluates to the class variable `test.count`.

In `t1`, you've created a **completely different** instance variable `count` that just happens to have the same name as the class variable. `t1.count` therefore returns this instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because instance attributes shadow class attributes, but they are *independent*.

When you try to access `t2.count`, there is no instance attribute (`t2.__dict__` does not have a `count` key), so Python next looks at `type(t2)` to see if it can find the attribute there. The class *does* have such an attribute, so `test.count` is returned.

`t1.count` on the other hand finds the instance attribute and returns that. `test.count` is never considered.